# What use is having multiple URL's in a Slack Outgoing Webhook Integration?

Tags: url, webhooks, slack-api, slack

Since multiple URL's are possible in the configuration what use or behavior of it would be? Are there any benefits to having multiple URL's instead of only the one?

Currently I only have a single URL in the configuration.